# How to create a Sybase stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I'm new to Sybase and i need to create a stored procedure to gather space, basically convert these into a procedure:

```
create proc sp_maint
  @dbname varchar(30), @segname varchar(30),
  @devname varchar(30), @devsize int,
  @freesize int, @free_percentage int 
as declare @sizeinpg float,
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what does not work?

Comment: the syntax im using is wrong

Comment: Right now, you've only given us a snippet of code, and not the full proc.  Hard to tell what you are doing wrong with just your variables...are you planning on selecting that data from system tables at some point?

Comment: when i try to copy the proc into the window gives me messages as

Answer (score 1):

```
create proc sp_maint
  @dbname varchar(30),
  @segname varchar(30),
  @devname varchar(30),
  @devsize int,
  @freesize int,
  @free_percentage int 
as
declare @sizeinpg float,
        @perc     float,
        @segbit   int,
        @seg      int,
        @pagefl   float
BEGIN
/* for all segments */
  select @seg = segment
  from syssegments
  where name = @segname
select DATE=convert(char(8),getdate(),1),
        DB_NAME=db,
        SEGMENT_NAME=seg,
        Allocated_Space=convert(int,(round(size,0))),
        Free_Space=convert(int,round(MBfree,0)),
        Free_Percent=convert(int,(round(((MBfree/size)*100),1))),
/* get rid of blanks */
  select @dbname = ltrim(rtrim(@dbname))
  select @segname = ltrim(rtrim(@segname))
**strong text**
```